# The ERC-20 Token Transfer might have Failed (ErrCode: unable to locate corresponding Transfer event log), check with sender

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum

EtherScan.io is showing error:  The ERC-20 Token Transfer might have Failed (ErrCode: unable to locate corresponding Transfer event log), check with sender.

Transactions are successful but users are not receiving tokens. Can someone help to explain what error is hiding?

Out of gas error? But not all provided gas was used.

Transaction example: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x20081e3012905d97961c2f1a18e1f3fe39f72a46b24e078df2fe446051366dca

Comment: same thing happened to me with shapeshift.io and i am still waiting a reply. just pisses me off. I use it quite often, but i don't think i will again, it is nerve wracking.

Comment: Me neither. I tried to send my token several times but I could not.

Comment: I have tried to send my tokens twice as well and get the same error message. Anyone knows why it happens, and how to correct it? I made sure of lots of gas money.

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I debug these sorts of problems:

- Click the contract address you sent to
- Find a transaction WITHOUT a red/orange (!) symbol
- Compare it to your failed one
- Repeat for another one

Sometimes it's the gas limit—it wants a higher gas limit like 200000. Sometimes there is no difference. If you can't tell, your best bet is to reach out to the token creators and ask them. They hopefully have more specific troubleshooting tips for you.